# I want a way to make my drupal front template base on current user

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7

I want a way to make my drupal site changing the template user based on the current user , for exemple when user one is connected the site is displayed by the template 1 and if user 2 is connected the site is displayed with template 2 and if anyone is connected it's displayed with the default template

thank you :)

Comment: great to hear that you want to do something. I go now, because i got better stuff to do than compliment you. Oh and please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) and the [How do i ask a good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because you didn't show us any effort or some code

Comment: Nochance to get your homework done :)

Answer (score 1):

Best to ask Drupalistas.  You could try this:

With the Bartek theme in Drupal 7 you can do something in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
if($logged_in && $front_page) {
    global $user;
    include __DIR__ . '/user_templates/user-' . $user->uid . '.tpl.php';
} else {
...


?>
```

Comment: @bub, perhaps.  But Drupal has globals: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/7

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite this module [Role Theme Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher). It provides theme-dependendy on user's role. you can also create (or download) some themes and use this module [Theme Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey). It may help...